# matching 2 data frames by row number and row name and extracting values from the first df when a match occurs

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

Sorry if the title is not clear or I am not explaining this well.

I have a scoring matrix as a data frame that looks like:

```
    1          2          3          4         5 6          7        8         9        10
L 40.220674 17.3635308 17.3635308 17.3635308  9.867452 0  0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
M 29.589501 19.1056911 19.1056911 19.1056911 14.285714 0 10.0000000 6.842105 1.4736842 0.1052632
I 13.761672 10.1045296 10.1045296 10.1045296  0.000000 0  0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
Y 25.085714 21.4285714 21.4285714 21.4285714 12.223859 0  0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
W  3.555865  0.8130081  0.8130081  0.8130081  0.000000 0  0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
K  2.700859  0.2322880  0.2322880  0.2322880  1.325479 0  2.6315789 3.684211 2.6315789 2.1052632
S  8.739141  6.9105691  6.9105691  6.9105691  0.000000 0  0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
V  1.969431  0.2322880  0.2322880  0.2322880  0.000000 0  3.4736842 3.684211 2.5263158 0.1052632
```

Each row corresponds to a different amino acid and each column is the position of that amino acid in a peptide.

I also have a df of many peptides indicating the amino acid in each position of the peptide.

```
pep_1 pep_2 pep_3
1      M     A     C
2      A     C     L
3      C     L     W
4      L     W     S
5      W     S     F
6      S     F     S
7      F     S     W
8      S     W     P
9      W     P     S
10     P     S     C
11     S     C     F
12     C     F     L
13     F     L     S
14     L     S     L
```

I am trying to match each peptide to the score matrix and when an amino acid is in the same position as it is in the scoring matrix, I want to export and sum all those values for each peptide.

I have tried unsuccessfully using plyr::match_df.

Is there a higher order function or package that may be able to accomplish this? Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: "when an amino acid is in the same position as it is in the scoring matrix" by that you mean that you want to associate the value (call it x) of the `i` row for each peptide in the second df, with the value on the `i` column and row that is named x in the first df? Then sum the column of each `pep_i`?

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro, yes that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: @poconel3 but then shouldn't the second data frame have the same number of columns as the first has of rows?

Comment: Plus, the amino acids on the second df can be `"M" "A" "C" "L" "W" "S" "F" "P"`, while the first have other options (row names) `"L" "M" "I" "Y" "W" "K" "S" "V"`. Shouldn't these two be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could reshape both the datasets into 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, then do a join with `left_join` on the matching columns, and reshape the output back to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
df2 %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, values_to = 'pep') %>% 
    left_join(df1 %>% 
              rownames_to_column('pep') %>% 
              pivot_longer(cols = -pep, names_to = 'rn') %>% 
              mutate(rn = as.integer(rn))) %>% 
    select(-pep) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`1` = c(40.220674, 29.589501, 13.761672, 25.085714, 
3.555865, 2.700859, 8.739141, 1.969431), `2` = c(17.3635308, 
19.1056911, 10.1045296, 21.4285714, 0.8130081, 0.232288, 6.9105691, 
0.232288), `3` = c(17.3635308, 19.1056911, 10.1045296, 21.4285714, 
0.8130081, 0.232288, 6.9105691, 0.232288), `4` = c(17.3635308, 
19.1056911, 10.1045296, 21.4285714, 0.8130081, 0.232288, 6.9105691, 
0.232288), `5` = c(9.867452, 14.285714, 0, 12.223859, 0, 1.325479, 
0, 0), `6` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `7` = c(0, 10, 
0, 0, 0, 2.6315789, 0, 3.4736842), `8` = c(0, 6.842105, 0, 0, 
0, 3.684211, 0, 3.684211), `9` = c(0, 1.4736842, 0, 0, 0, 2.6315789, 
0, 2.5263158), `10` = c(0, 0.1052632, 0, 0, 0, 2.1052632, 0, 
0.1052632)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("L", "M", "I", 
"Y", "W", "K", "S", "V"))

df2 <- structure(list(pep_1 = c("M", "A", "C", "L", "W", "S", "F", "S", 
"W", "P", "S", "C", "F", "L"), pep_2 = c("A", "C", "L", "W", 
"S", "F", "S", "W", "P", "S", "C", "F", "L", "S"), pep_3 = c("C", 
"L", "W", "S", "F", "S", "W", "P", "S", "C", "F", "L", "S", "L"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"))
```

Comment: Trying this solution now. It looks like the first mutate call is throwing this error: Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: I corrected this by using: rownames_to_column(., var = "rn") in place of your mutate call. However, now the Left_join call is having issues throwing the following error: Joining, by = c("rn", "pep")
Error: Can't join on `x$rn` x `y$rn` because of incompatible types.
ℹ `x$rn` is of type <character>>.
ℹ `y$rn` is of type <integer>>.

Comment: @poconnel3 if you check my code, I did a correction with `mutate(rn = as.integer(rn))` to match the type

Comment: @poconnel3 if you use `rownames_to_column`, it is a `character` class and with `row_number`, it is `integer`, that is the reason I changed to `as.integer`.  With `rownames_to-column`, you may not need that conversion because both are character

Comment: OK, got it. something was just masking mutate from dplyr on my end. After correcting that it works perfect! Thank you for this tidy solution!

Comment: @poconnel3 if that is the case, you can use `dplyr::mutate` because there is `plyr::mutate` also which can mask the function when both are loaded